# media queries with images html5 firefox chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox, media-queries

I'm having 2 problems with media queries and HTML5.

The below code in the `<body>` section of an `html` file, is in a div that's given an id name of `social_networks`.

**Problems**

1) delicious_old.jpg does not show on devices whose screen width is upto 375px.

Tested with Chrome 36.0.1985.135 on an LG L20.

2) delicious.jpg does not show on devices whose screen width is from 375px to 2560px.

Tested with Firefox in Ubuntu 14.01 - 15 inch monitor.

I've search on SO, and Google and read lots of articles and questions but not come across one yet that solve them.

**Code**:

```
<figure>
    <!-- low-res, default -->
    <source src="/resources/delicious_old.jpg" media="(min-device-width: 0px) and (max-device-width: 375px)">

    <!-- medium-res -->
    <source src="/resources/delicious.jpg" media="(min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 2560px)">

    <!-- Fallback content -->
    <!--<a href="<long web page>"><img src="/resources/delicious.jpg" alt="Add to Delicious"></a>-->
</figure>
```

Above code updated following comments.

Please advise

Comment: you're aware that this is an experimental technology and is only available on chrome 38+ and firefox 33+ (off by default). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture
and shouldn't be used for production

Comment: @FabioG Ok I didn't know that thanks. Also what would you suggest instead - eg take out `<picture>` tags?

Comment: you could use <figure> and <figcatpion> instead

Comment: @JustinBreiland @FabioG I've just tried with `<figure>` tags however the same problems in question (1 and 2) are occuring. Html code has been updated.

Comment: Is your source for images correct? Try removing the first "/" .  If it still doesn't work, it could be your media query.  Change min-device-width: 376px;  It may be conflicting with the first queries max-width.

Comment: First, `<picture>` and `<figure>` are two different things. They don't have the same content models! So don't mix features of the two, that won't work. Secondly, `<picture>` works only in the latest browsers (Chrome >=38; Firefox >=33), and in Firefox only even if you set _dom.image.picture.enabled_ and _dom.image.srcset.enabled_ to true in the about:config screen. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture). Thirdly, both `<figure>` and `<picture>` need an `<img>` in their content. You seem to be missing that in your code.

Comment: @JustinBreiland the location of the images are correct. I will experiment with the media queries. I'll consider <img> tags. I'll update question and code soon.